# Importing DEM in ASCII format into ArcMap and Projecting it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, dem, esri-ascii-raster

I have been trying to import an ascii grid file into ArcMap.

However, I am battling to project the data.

Can anyone assist?

I've tried defining the projection but to no avail. The data should be located at roughly the following coordinates... 29. S 26. E.

See .asc header information below:

```
ncols         990
nrows         1140
xllcenter     -97500
yllcenter    -3237675
cellsize      25
NODATA_value  -9999
```

Comment: Would be easier if you actually say which country this data is for?

Comment: You should not have to "import" ASCII grid files - ArcMap can load these natively and should project on the fly as well.  Area there any issues if you set ArcMap data frame to the "target" coordinate system then add the grid files to the map?

Comment: Looking at the xllcenter and yllcenter the coordinates are really bad! It's not often they are legitimately negative and especially not the Y coordinate. Based on the cell size this should be in a projected coordinates, at a punt I'd try WGS84 UTM Zone 35 **North** which would put this data in *The Deomocratic Republic of Congo*, does that sound right?

Comment: @Jakub - you are right, but you have to know that target coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

From the lat/lon coordinates, the data should be in South Africa, near Bloemfontein:

[image]

The coordinates of xll and yll (lower left) might fit the South African Cape coordinate System. The proj string for it is:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=enu +a=6378249.145 +b=6356514.966398753 +towgs84=-136,-108,-292,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

This is **NOT** the official EPSG definition 22287, but rather the north-oriented one implemented in latest QGIS. I have no access to Arcgis, but you should be able to define that projection too.

The blue points are in that projection. Coordinates for the upper right corner are:

```
xurcenter = xllcenter + ncols * cellsize
yurcenter = yllcenter + nrows * cellsize
```